# Whether it is appropriate to use Entity Framework versus ADO.NET for multi table joins?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a Web API with a couple of endpoints. Each endpoint queries the database and it involves a join between 2 to 6 tables.

I have previously used Entity Framework, but only for single tables. So I want to ask whether it is appropriate to use Entity Framework for multiple table joins, or should I stick with ADO.NET based SQL queries?

Comment: I'd almost say: it's not appropriate to use EF for single tables only. Getting object graphs from a relational database is the core business of any O/R mapper. Navigation properties are at the heart of EF's querying features.

Comment: The navigation is achieved via LINQ or is there any other alternative? Just curious.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  EF enables you to express the query logic using LINQ queries over your entities, and will translate to SQL.  It's a core function of EF, and it's very common to see it used in a Web API to fetch Entities from the database, and then serialize the Entities as JSON for sending to the client.

Using EF's built-in database-to-Entity mapping and .NET's built-in Entity-to-JSON mapping makes writing a Web API very simple.

Of course you should monitor the SQL generated by EF, and there are scenarios where you might drop down to [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), Dapper, or ADO.NET.  But for the basic use case of building a simple Web API, EF Core + ASP.NET Core is the simplest answer.

See eg [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)